# Mongodb get date from time string in current day

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like below

```
//Collection design
[
  {
    "str": "09:00:00"
  }
]


// aggregate pipeline
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$str",
          format: "%H:%M:%S",
          timezone: "Asia/Kolkata"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

//Expected Output in Indian Time

[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "date": ISODate("2020-04-30T03:30:00.000Z")
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first convert your date to `ISODate`.

You can `$concat` with the below `moment` format.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: { $concat: [moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDT"), "$str"] },
          timezone: "Asia/Kolkata"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help.  Is there any other way without using moment, directly getting today date (2020-04-30) and concating ["2020-04-30", "T", "09:00:00" ]

Comment: Well I do prefer `moment` as it is best to get all the formats.

Comment: till yesterday everything work correctly but today getting error with mongoose update  ----   ""you cannot pass in a date/time string with time zone information ('T') together with a timezone argument"

Comment: please help me.

Comment: Remove the T from the moment and concat it

Comment: can we give " " inplace of t

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar Removing `T` will also work. https://mongoplayground.net/p/0rJhWzSASy8

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query, where [$$NOW](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.NOW) would return current datetime value :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateFromParts: {
          year: { $year: "$$NOW" },
          month: { $month: "$$NOW" },
          day: { $dayOfMonth: "$$NOW" },
          hour: { $toInt: { $substrBytes: ["$str", 0, 2] } },
          minute: { $toInt: { $substrBytes: ["$str", 3, 2] } },
          second: { $toInt: { $substrBytes: ["$str", 6, 2] } },
          timezone: "Asia/Kolkata",
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ODktCLrMioi)

**Update :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: {
            $concat: [
              {
                $dateToString: {
                  format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                  date: "$$NOW",
                  timezone: "Asia/Kolkata"
                }
              },
              "T",
              "$str"
            ]
          },
          timezone: "Asia/Kolkata"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jG4OCGzNGUT)

Comment: nice effort but if from the frontend   if only  9:0:0 your solution will not work,  your solution will work efficiently if  11:33:55 like values  if all are 2 digits HH:mm:ss

Comment: I also taught of implementing a similar workaround. but it is not feasible in all scenarios

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar : Yes agreed I even thought so, that's all with data, whole point of this answer is to use `$$NOW` :-) You can actually still use same query with `$split` & `$arrayElemAt` to make it work for `9:0:0` but without doing all those things we can achieve most with new query.

Answer (score 0):

Like the above solution posted by @Ashh

I like another approach for my question without using moment dependency

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: new Date()
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateToString: {
          date: "$date",
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          timezone: "Asia/Kolkata"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: {
            $concat: [
              "$date",
              "T",
              "$str",

            ]
          },
          timezone: "Asia/Kolkata"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```